# Delete a users data from SQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, crud

Hi im trying to delete a users booking detials when the user clicks delete in my bookingbeforedeltion.php file but for some reason when I test my php file once I click delete it goes to my delete.php screen and says it failed to delete from database and has the error Undefined index: rn. Is my rn not defined? Sorry Im new to this. Here is my code below:

bookingbeforedeltion.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>BookingBeforeDeletion</title> </head>
<body>

<?php
include "config.php"; 
$DBC = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER , DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);


if (!$DBC) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.\n". 
mysqli_connect_errno()."=".mysqli_connect_error() ;
exit; 
};


echo "<pre>";  

$query = 'SELECT roomname, checkindate, checkoutdate FROM booking';

$result = mysqli_query($DBC,$query);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


echo "Delete Bookings" ?><p><?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "Room name: ".$row['roomname'] . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Check in date: ".$row['checkindate'] . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Check out date: ".$row['checkoutdate'] . PHP_EOL;
  ?>

    <a href= 'delete.php?rn=$result[roomname]'>Delete</a> <a href="index.php">[Cancel]</a>
   
  <?php
  echo "<hr />";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
echo "</pre>";


echo "Connectted via ".mysqli_get_host_info($DBC); 

mysqli_close($DBC);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

delete.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head><title>BookingBeforeDeletion</title> </head>
body>

<?php
include "config.php"; 
$DBC = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER , DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);


if (!$DBC) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL.\n". 
mysqli_connect_errno()."=".mysqli_connect_error() ;
exit; 
};


echo "<pre>";  

$roomname=$_GET['rn'];
$query = "DELETE bookingID, roomname, checkindate, checkoutdate, contactnumber,
bookingextras, roomreview, customerID, roomID FROM booking WHERE roomname = 
'$roomname'";
$result = mysqli_query($DBC,$query);

if($result)
{
echo "<font color='green'> Booking deleted from database";
}
else {
echo "<font color='red'> Failed to delete booking from database";
}

?>
```

Comment: You should really be looking to delete by `bookingId` not `roomename`. If `roomname` is not unique you will delete **all** bookings for that room name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

and I think this will help:

1. As mentioned above, you need to print it from the `PHP`

```
<a href= 'delete.php?rn=$result[roomname]'>
// To 
<a href= 'delete.php?rn=<?= $row['roomname'] ?>'>
// Explanation:
// 1. <?= ... ?> is the short form of <?php echo ... ?>
// 2. The `roomname` came from $row, not $result ($result is the MySQLi Object)
// 3. You need to quote the `roomname` because without it `roomname` will be readed
//    as Constant, and may Throw a Warning message
//
```

2. Your `DELETE` is incorrect, the correct one is `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...`

```
$query = "DELETE bookingID, roomname, checkindate, checkoutdate, contactnumber,
bookingextras, roomreview, customerID, roomID FROM booking WHERE roomname = 
'$roomname'";
// To
$query = "DELETE FROM booking WHERE roomname = '$roomname'";
```

EXTRA:
3. You can assign a default value to $roomname

```
$roomname=$_GET['rn'];
// To
$roomname=$_GET['rn'] ?? 'default if null';

// if the rn index doesnt exist, the $roomname value will be `default if null` instead of throwing a Warning
```

4. Try to use `Prepared-Statement` SQL instead of writing it. (I dont know the example, but it can prevent SQL Injection)